# https leads to another subdomain than http

Tags: wordpress, redirect, https

I got the following problem,

yesterday I would like to publish our new scout homepage for this we bought an Alpha SSL Certificate to make it more secure for users.

Now when type in https://www.domain.at I become redirected to https://subdomain.domain.at how can that happen?
When I type http://www.domain.at I don't become redirected.

I have placed an simple html file inside the folder, for testing if it comes from the domain settings but https://www.domain.at/test.html leads to my orignal folders html file.

It seems to me that Wordpress redirects me to another subdomain when using https.
But I can't find the reason in the database or any other setting.

My hoster is domainfactory(df.eu).

Thanks,

Programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, the problem solved itself it seems that the configuration took time to take effect